# Optimal way to Assemble a file

Tags: shell, file

I have a large number of small files with sequential filenames & I want to create a single file out of it. What is the fastest way to do this?

e.g.

```
1.tgz.1  1.tgz.2  1.tgz.3   =========> 1.tgz
```

Comment: Don't really think this is what the 'assembler' tag refers to.  Actually, not to sure why Java and C are tagged either.

Comment: That's probably why the user is an 'unknown yahoo'. :-) (sorry @unknown (yahoo))

Comment: I have retagged the question.

Comment: The program need not only be in shell. It cud be in C, java or whatever. i need the fastest one.

Comment: The fastest one is cat. It exists since the beginning of Unix. Chances are that some smart people have already optimized it as much as possible. If you want to increase time performance, think of upgrading your hardware.

Answer (score 8):

You could [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the files from the shell.

In Windows (`/b` for binary mode):

```
copy /b   1.tgz.1 + 1.tgz.2 + 1.tgz.3   1.tgz
```

In Unix/Linux:

```
cat   1.tgz.1 1.tgz.2 1.tgz.3   > 1.tgz
```

Comment: that's taking quite some time...can it be further optimized?

Comment: I think cat is about the quickest operation you're going to get!

Comment: Even if it could be optimized, I guess that the optimization would gain nothing compared to the time spent by gunzip and tar on the big file.

Comment: On Unix/Linux, you can save some disk space by piping cat and tar: cat 1.tgz.1 1.tgz.2 1.tgz.3 | tar xzf -

Answer (score 2):

If it's a **large** number of small files, you don't want to be messing around with a huge number of arguments.

Since most UNIX shells expand wildcards alphabetically, you should use:

```
cat 1.tgz.? 1.tgz.?? 1.tgz.??? >1.tgz
```

That's assuming there are between 100 and 999 files inclusive, adjust the arguments to handle more or less (e.g., add 1.tgz.???? if there's between 1,000 and 9,9999 inclusive). You're not going to get better performance since your bottle neck is the disk speed which is always going to be slower than the code running on the CPU.

The only other possibilities I can think of are:

- create 1.tgz on a separate physical disk. This may give you the advantage of interleaving disk accesses.
- run as root and use `nice` to bump up your priority (see `man nice` for details). This will improve your power to get more CPU but again, if you're bound by disk I/O, that won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

This is bash (your shell may vary):

```
for n in *.tgz.* ; do cat $n >> ${n/tgz.*/tgz} ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get better performance using [dd](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/dd.html) with a high block size:

```
for n in *.tgz.* ; \
  dd if="$n" conv=notrunc oflag=append bs=4M of="somefile.tgz" ; \
done
```